# how to judge which button has been clicked using there className instead of ID

Tags: javascript

I have 100 buttons in a table having same class name but different id c-1,c-2,....,c-n `<input type="button" class="btn-c" id="c-1" value="ADD">`
how will i Know which button has been clicked using their className and whithout using onclick event on the each button
`<input type="button" ... onclick="call_function(this);"`
for simplicity let say I want to `alert(button.id);` on the click of any of the 100 buttons

Comment: Read through this page on event basics: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: Next time do not tag it jQuery to start if you do not want to use jQuery. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have so many buttons, it makes sense to use event delegation:

```
$('table').on('click', '.btn-c', function() {
    alert(this.id); // will get you clicked button id
});
```

This is optimal approach for performance standpoint as you bind only one event handler to parent element and benefit from child element event bubbling.

**UPD.** This is pure javascript version of the same code:

```
document.getElementById('table').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (/\bbtn-c\b/.test(e.target.className)) {
        alert(e.target.id);
    }
}, false);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zn0os4n8/

Comment: i have the thing work with jquery but i have to use javascript only not any kind of library like jquery

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery - attach a click handler to the common class and use the instance of `this` to get the id of the clicked button

```
$(".btn-c").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); //id of the clicked button
});
```

Comment: i want to use java-script instead of Jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach an event to a parent element and listen for the clicks. You can than use the event object to determine what is being clicked on. You can check if it is the element you want and do whatever you want.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {  //attach to element that is a parent of the buttons
    var clickedElem = e.target;  //find the element that is clicked on
    var isC = (clickedElem.classList.contains("c"));  //see if it has the class you are looking for
    var outStr = isC ? "Yes" : "No";  //just outputting something to the screen
    document.getElementById("out").textContent = outStr + " : "  +  clickedElem.id;    
});
```

```html
<button class="d" id="b0">x</button>
<button class="c" id="b1">y</button>
<button class="c" id="b2">y</button>
<button class="c" id="b3">y</button>
<button class="d" id="b4">x</button>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Note: this is not going to work in older IEs without polyfills.